# rxjs iif operator with multiple conditions

Tags: angular, rxjs

What is the best way to return Observables based on multiple conditions?

This is how my code is set up right now:

```js
iif(
    () => !this.id,
    this.service.listStuff$(),
    this.service.listStuffById$(this.id)
).pipe(
    switchMap((list: List) => {
        // ...
    })
).subscribe();
```

I want to add another condition `this.name` such that

```js
if (this.id) {
    return this.service.listStuffById$(this.id)
} else if (this.name) {
    return this.service.listStuffByName$(this.name)
} else {
    return this.service.listStuff$()
}
```

Would the best solution be to chain two `iif`s?

Comment: *Personal opinion*: An if-else statement will be much simpler for your scenario.

Comment: @YongShun Suppose you're right. I can wrap the if-else in a helper function, then call the `pipe` on the result of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always nest the `iif` calls, since [`ObserveableInput`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/type-alias/ObservableInput) types are also `Observable`s.

```js
iif(
    () => this.id,
    // if (this.id) {
    this.service.listStuffById$(this.id),
    iff(
        () => this.name,
        // } else if (this.name) {
        this.service.listStuffByName$(this.name),
        // } else {
        this.service.listStuff$()
        // }
    )
).pipe(
    switchMap((list: List) => {
        ...  
    }),
).subscribe();
```